# Non-existing icon generated in manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created a project with a template that included a launcher icon called `Icon`. I received the right one to use so I changed it, and named it `ic_launcher`.

I changed the name on the manifest:

`android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"`

And in the launcher activity annotation:

`[Activity(Label = "[...]", MainLauncher = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Icon = "@drawable/ic_launcher")]`

When I build the project, the IDE generates a complete `AndroidManifest` (located at `\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml`) that contains the right icon names, except for this line:

`<activity android:configChanges="[...]" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="[...]" android:name="[...]" />`

Which says; `android:icon="@drawable/icon"`. I searched the text in the project and found nothing.

The file is generated in every build, so no matter what I try, it's always changed back and thus, I can't deploy.

Any ideas?

Yes, I know I can just rename `ic_launcher` to `Icon` but I want to try to do the right thing first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an internal talk, it turns out a library was generating that activity declaration. That definition was then added to the manifest of the project and causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Android by default takes up 'ic_launcher' drawable which is an Android Logo. Trying changing the name to something different like 'app_logo' and try refreshing/Cleaning and rebuilding the project.

UPDATE:
As the change of name doesn't work yet, follow these steps.

1. Uninstall the app completely and try building and installing.
2. Make sure the icon with the other name say '**app_name**' is placed in **all density folders**.
3. Ensure that you don't have an Icon Activity definition in your Main Activity because this overrides the manifest. It a very common situation.
   More info on this [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59546/cannot-change-icon-from-default-xamarin-icon)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Android. I already tried rebuild, clean and restarting the IDE.

Comment: Yes.. I got it. Please change the name and try it again.

Comment: I renamed it many times, it works when it's named _Icon_, but doesn't work when named anything else.